# Error in sending json to server in android

Tags: android, json, http-post

I have written this code for sending json to the server

```
protected String doInBackground(Integer...params) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://juelminapp.visualsparks.net/ws/login");
    try {
        // Add your data
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.accumulate("method", "login");
        obj.accumulate("email", "adilshafique@hotmail.com");
        obj.accumulate("password", "Adil2014$");
        obj.accumulate("submit", "Login");
        JSONObject o2 = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(obj);
        o2.put("customer", array);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(o2.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        data = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

It gives response as method is not defined. the descrption of the server is as follow
Web service url

> http://juelminapp.visualsparks.net/ws/login

Sending format in json requirement. You need to send method post and all the json array assign to customer array key and then web  service get it from customer through post method.

i.e in php

```
array("customer"=>$jsondata)
```

Then web service receive all the json data in this customer post value the posted fields name are below:

```
method => 'login',
email => adilshafique@hotmail.com
password => Adil2014$
submit => Login
```

Same as it the first is posted field name and 2nd is data. Please use the same post field name.

The message that will return Method undefined, Invalid Password, User ID is not found in our database.

Your account is not activated yet.Entered Primary Email exists in Database, use another 
Username.

In case of successfully login, Session id will return

PHP

```
$url = 'http://juelminapp.visualsparks.net/ws/login';
$data = array('method' = > 'login', 'email' = > 'adilshafique@hotmail.com', 'password' = > 'Adil2014$', 'submit' = > 'Login');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data_string = urlencode(json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("customer" = > $data_string));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are sending a simple http entity, when the server is expecting as a multipart form data. Try this,

```
protected String doInBackground(Integer...params) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://juelminapp.visualsparks.net/ws/login");
    try {
        // Add your data
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.accumulate("method", "login");
        obj.accumulate("email", "adilshafique@hotmail.com");
        obj.accumulate("password", "Adil2014$");
        obj.accumulate("submit", "Login");
        String urlEncodedData = URLEncoder.encode(obj.toString(), "utf-8");

        // Changed Here to MultiPartEntity

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("customer", new StringBody(urlEncodedData));
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);


        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        data = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

This should work for you. Hope this helps!